# Default instance for Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

My questionis:  is there anyway to create a default instance for class Language? Like this :

```
class Language(models.
     default_instance = Language(name="unknown")
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

so class Student can use this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
         language = models.ForeignKey(Language, default = Language.default_instance.pk )
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Language.objects.get_or_create` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could set it by overriding the save method:

```
#your model
class Student(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  language = models.ForeignKey(Language)

    # override save
    def save(self,**args,**kwargs):
      if self.language is None:
        default_language = Language.objects.get(pk=1) #set to default
        self.language = default_language
    super(Student,self).save(self,*args,**kwargs) # the 'real' save
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) about overriding the save method.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy S!